# Invalid operands to binary expression (while comparing object to 0)

Tags: c++

```
//Default Constructor
bigint::bigint() {
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
        digits[i] = 0;
}

//Overloaded operator==
bool bigint::operator==(const bigint& rhs) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
        if (digits[i] == rhs.digits[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Following error message is given while compiling the program. I've spend hours googling and making changes, but no success.

```
test_default_ctor.cpp:18:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('bigint' and 'int')
    assert(bi == 0);
           ~~ ^  ~
```

```
bigint bi;

// Verify
assert(bi == 0);
std::cout << "0 == " << bi << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please post the entire code. Otherwise, the error is clear: it seems you don't have an operator that compares a `bigint` with an `int`, and no conversion operator either (to use the one shown in your code).

Comment: `'bigint' and 'int'` well, implement a `bool bigint:operator==(int other)` method...

Answer (score 0):

Your `bigint` class is likely missing either:

- a constructor that takes an `int` as input.
- an `operator==` that takes an `int` as input.

Adding either of those (preferably the constructor) would fix the error.

Also, the `operator==` you have shown is implemented wrong. It will return true if *any single digit* matches, even if all of the *other digits* do not. You need to compare *all* digits before returning true, eg:

```
bool bigint::operator==(const bigint& rhs) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
        if (digits[i] != rhs.digits[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```